# string manipulation in c++

Tags: c++

I have a string interface (const char* value, uint32_t length) which I need to manipulate.

1) I have to make it all lower case

2) I have to remove all characters found after the ';' semicolon

Can anyone help point me to any C/C++ libraries that can do this? without me having to iterate  through the char array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean "without explicitly iterating"? because, irrespective of what approach/library you use, it has to go through all characters!

Comment: I think, OP meant: "I don't want to write the loop on my own".I know, I am a mind reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
```

2)

```
str = str.substr(0, str.find(";"));
```

Answer (score 2):

See here: **http://ideone.com/fwJx5**:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string interface(const char* value, uint32_t length)
{
    std::string s(value, length);
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [] (char ch) { return std::tolower(ch); });
    return s.substr(0, s.find(";"));
}

int main()
{
     std::cout << interface("Test Case Number 1; ignored text", 32) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
test case number 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do (2) first as it will potentially give (1) less work to do.

If you're sticking with traditional C functions, you can use `strchr()` to find the first ';' and either replace that with '\0' (if the string is mutable) or use pointer arithmetic to copy to another buffer.

You can use `tolower()` to convert an ASCII (I'm assuming you're using ASCII) to lowercase but you'll have to iterate through your remaining loop to do this.

For example:

```
const char* str = "HELLO;WORLD";

// Make a mutable string - you might not need to do this
int strLen = strlen( str );
char mStr[ strLen + 1];
strncpy( mStr, str, strLen );

cout << mStr << endl; // Prints "HELLO;WORLD"

// Get rid of the ';' onwards.
char* e = strchr( mStr, ';' );
*e = '\0';

cout << mStr << endl; // Prints "HELLO"

for ( char* p = mStr; p != e; *p = tolower(*p), p++ );

cout << mStr << endl; // Prints "hello"
```

Comment: @CodeBlocks: Thanks, but unless you have a very good reason to stick with old, C-style functions, I'd strongly suggest you give AljoshaBre's answer a look. As you can see, from a C++ perspective, it's much more elegant.